# Wrong characters highlighted in .pdf

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I'm trying to create a resume using latex. But when I highlight some text, the wrong characters are parsed/selected in various different pdf readers (adbobe, chrome, firefox, etc.)

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\textheight=10in
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedright

% DEFINITIONS FOR RESUME %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\lineunder} {
    \vspace*{-8pt} \\
    \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\
}

\newcommand{\header} [1] {{
    \hspace*{-18pt}\vspace*{
        6pt} \textsc{#1}}
    \vspace*{-6pt} \lineunder
}

% END RESUME DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-40pt}

%==== Profile ====%
\vspace*{-10pt}
\begin{center}
    {\Huge \scshape {Abcdefghi}}\\
\end{center}

%==== Education ====%
\header{Education}

\ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting... For me it works with Okular when I compile with LuaTeX. If I compile with XeTeX I can't even select the small cap characters. The issue appears with `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\begin{document}
Hello \textsc{World}
\end{document}`.

Comment: It appears to depend on the specific font used (i.e., the way small caps are implemented in the font). With, for example Calibri Light I get the same bevavior as @PhelypeOleinik, but with something like TeX Gyre Termes it works fine with both LuaTeX ad XeTeX (using Evince as viewer).